# Array and String multiplication

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2d array from a tsv file. The array is called `root` and have the following information:

```
HG  sn  FA  
PC  2   16:0
PI  1   18:0
PS  3   20:0
PE  2   24:0
        26:0
        16:1
        18:2
```

Then i have some Strings:

```
 String lc = 34:2 // It is a user input so it could be another number
 String result = 2 // again a user input so it could be 1,2 or 3
```

34:2 is a number not something that should be divided.

I need to get values from the row FA in the array the `root[i][2]` which summed together can be value of String lc. String result is telling me how many values that should be summed together, if its 1,2 or 3.

An example:

```
String lc = 34:2
String result = 2
```

This means that i need to find 2 values in the array from row FA that summed together will equal 34:2, this could be 16:1+18:1.

I need to get both values from the array printed.

Comment: No offense, but using arrays in Java and other similarly high level languages is rarely (if ever) a good idea. You rather need to both think OO and use collections...

Comment: @Powerslave Why should it generally be a bad idea? Arrays are the right way to handle vectors. Which data structure depends on the data and and the way you want to access it.

Comment: So is your 2D array full of strings? I'm finding it very difficult to understand what you want to achieve - how does one multiple strings? Your example with `x` and `y` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Duncan, my 2d array come s from a tsv file. i want to multiply a string with the array, so i can get a combination of FA out. see me edit, hope it helps.

Comment: @Matteo There's a `Vector` class available (or `ArrayList` for example, if you want to avoid synchronization overhead). And also there are other collections available. Arrays are rigid and in many cases they also tend to make the code less readable. Use of them most often indicates that the design of the system is inappropriate. Arrays were once thought of as a good idea to handle vectors - in the time of old low-level languages like C. In the same time, thinking about implementing low level structures such as vectors and the like also flag that something went wrong in the design phase.

Comment: @Powerslave Sorry but I disagree. Implementing matrix multiplication with dynamic lists is simply nonsense. There are many data types that are better handled with arrays.

Comment: pls see my new edit. I hope i have calryfied it more what my question is

Comment: @Klaus the only way to do this, since your FA values are strings, is to iterate the array of strings, splitting each item and converting the values to numbers, then looking for matches to calculate the desired result. This will be extremely inefficient. What you really need is a different way of representing and storing the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't multiply a String and an int. You must convert your String to an int or a double before.

```
//String to double
double doubleVal = Double.parseDouble(stringVal);
//String to int 
int intVal = Integer.parseInt(stringVal);
```

Then you ca make any mathematic operation

```
//multiplication exemple
double result = doubleVal * 1234;
```

Then you can convert it back to a string if you want

```
//double to String
String s = ""+result;
```

**EDIT**  Okay 32:2 means 32.2 so here is the solution

```
    double x = 2.0; //you have your x doublevalue
    String y = "32:2"; //you have your y String value

    String nums = y.replace(":",".");
    double ydouble = Double.parseDouble(nums); // equal 32.2

    double res = ydouble / x; //32.2/2 = 16.1

    for (int i = 0; i < root.lenght; i++) {


        //same thing here, we convert the FA number to a double
        String nums = root[i][2].replace(":",".");
        double rdouble  = Double.parseDouble(nums);


        if(res == rdouble)
            return root[i][2]; //solution found

    }
    return null;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes i am converting the string. But how can i do `double result = doubleVal * root[i][2]`

Comment: What you want to do is not clear. root[i][2] is not always a number. What do you mean by FA? if i follow your explication: root[0][0] = "PC", root[0][1] = "2" and root[0][2]= "16:0" ?

Comment: root[0][0] = "HG", root[0][1] = "SN" and root[0][2]= "FA" root[1][0] = PC i hope you can follow now. I need to calculate the combination of FA to get a value. If i have String y = 32:2, then is should calculate that 16:1*2 is equal String y.

Comment: Okay, check again my answer I edited it. does it helps?

Comment: Just saw your edit, and first of something you misunderstood me or i was not very clear. The 32:2 should not be divided it is a number. i have just edited my original post, with some code. maybe you can help me ?

Comment: Maybe instead of : it should be converted to a . so it would be easier to calculate? then it can always be converted back later? The only problem here is that in the file i was given, the numbers are with :

Comment: Well for me 32:2 is not a number. I thought it means 32 dived by 2 (16). So what? 32:2 means 32.2 ?

Comment: I edited again, that should do it.